# How do I write a Django query that matches only the minute field of a DateTime column?

Tags: django, datetime, django-queryset, django-filter

I'm using Django 3.2 and PostGres 9.6.  I have this model with a "created" DateTime field ...

```
class PriceQuote(models.Model):
        ...
    created = models.DateTimeField(null=False, default=datetime.now)
```

How do I write a Django filter query that includes a clause to match the minute field of the created column?  So in the below

```
class PriceQuoteManager():
    def get_prices_per_hour(self, item):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        end_time = now.replace(second = 0, microsecond = 0)
        start_time = end_time - timedelta(days=1)
        return PriceQuote.objects.filter(
            item=item,
            created__range=[start_time, end_time],
            xxx=end_time.minute
        )
```

I want to replace "xxx" with a clause that says match the minute field of "created" with the minute field of the "end_time" variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`__minute`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#minute):

```
        return PriceQuote.objects.filter(
            item=item,
            created__range=[start_time, end_time],
            created__minute=end_time.minute
        )
```